# 502 bad gateway django + gcloud

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gcloud, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy my django site to gcloud, everything upload just fine but when I follow the link I get a 502 bad gateway error. I was following the gcloud tutorial for app engine with no luck.

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python 39

resources:
 memory_gb: 4

handlers: 
 url: /static/
 static_dir: /static/

url: /.*
script: auto
```

I'm new to django and gcloud so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space between `python` and `39`:

```
runtime: python39
```